# What is the proper word in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> I think the project is conducted for the intention X, and as a member
>   I need to know if any other intention is -----.
>
> I think the project is conducted for the intention X, and as a member
>   I need to know if there is any other intention -----.

What word/words to put in the blank. I like to use "involved" or "involved in it". Is it correct to use "involved" without "in it"? In general, which of the above sentences are prefered?

Comment: The second one seems correct to me. I think the project is conducted for the intention X, and as a member I need to know if there is any other intention. And there is no need to append any word after.

Comment: I might just say "any other reason for it." It seems more clear to me. In any case, I think I would use *for it* rather than *in it,* and wouldn't feel the need to find another verb.

Comment: Referring to my business-study and project-managment, the whole expression sounds weird. One reason: An experiment will be conducted for the purpose of finding out more about..... Another reason: A project has goals and proceeds different stages. In stage 1, you define goals, requirements, risks ect..

Comment: "conducted for the intention X" sounds really weird.  It's understandable, but very non-idiomatic.  More fluent would be "conducted *with the intention of* X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is fine without any word.

The first option could be completed with ***present*** or ***involved***, but either way it's a slightly awkward wording. Not incorrect, and not something that would mark someone out as a non-native speaker, but as someone who doesn't have the trick of forming elegant sentences (or at least hasn't applied that trick in this case).